# how do i display mysql data in marquee?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, marquee

i'm trying to use a marquee to display all the data from jobs table , but some how i can't display anything at all although it connects to the database successfully .so how can i display the data using marquee ?

```html
    <html>
    <body>
       <div class="box"  STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:110px; LEFT:1100px;height: 470px;width : 200px;padding:10px;" >
  <!-- STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:170px; LEFT:980px;height: 349px;width :360px;" -->
 <u><font size="3" color="white">- Jobs may inters you :</font></u>
 <br>
 <marquee direction="up" scrollamount="2">
  <p id="boxContent">
  <script>
  <?php
  $conn = new Mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ISNet");
  if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed:".$conn->connect_error);
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> position - ". $row["position"]. "<br> company- ". $row["company"].
        " <br> address -" . $row["Address"] ."<br> description - " . $row["description"] . " <br> mail -" . $row["mail"] .
         "<br>";
         echo "----------------------------------";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
  ?>
  </script></p>
 </marquee>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need to take it from mysql database first ..?

Comment: You have way too many unclosed questions. You should mark the ones as solved by accepting them.

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag is obsolete https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Answer (score 1):

This is what you do at the start of your marquee:

```
<marquee direction="up" scrollamount="2">
  <p id="boxContent">
  <script>
```

You open a script tag so everything you echo out, ends up inside the script tag and will be interpreted by the browser as javascript. So you will probably see a lot of errors in the console and your text in the source code.

Just remove the opening and closing script tags and you will have yourself a very cool retro marquee :-)

Comment: i advice you to accept answers ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ) if the answer helpt you out @reeena11

Comment: They brought the `<marquee>` tag back? *lol!* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee - I stopped using it when I first gotten wind of it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I don't know, it's been a while since I've seen one. Good old days!

Comment: @jeroen *heh!* - I guess it's been a while since you coded HTML ;-) and yeah, "the good 'ol days" when marqueeing was *that* simple. Now we have to use scripts that are like 50 times the size of what `<marquee>` does and used to do quite well I might add. *Sigh*.